# case statement in mysql not returning correct output

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to find row_number based on confirmed order by country but getting unique row number for same confirmed value.

Data looks like :

```
confirmed | country              | row_nmb |
+-----------+----------------------+---------+
|         1 | Australia            |       1 |
|         1 | Belgium              |       2 |
|         1 | Cambodia             |       3 |
|         1 | Canada               |       4 |
|         2 | China                |       5 |
|         2 | Egypt                |       6 |
|         2 | Finland              |       7 |
|         2 | Germany              |       8 |
|         2 | India                |       9 |
|         2 | Japan                |      10 |
|         2 | Mainland China       |      11 |
```

Code I am writing:

```
 select confirmed, country, @row_number:= CASE WHEN @confirmed:= confirmed THEN @row_number+1 ELSE 1 END as "row_nmb" from (select confirmed, country from COVID_DB.COVID2019 group by confirmed,country  order by confirmed, country) X , (select  @row_number:=0, @confirmed:= 0) t where confirmed <> 0 group by confirmed, country order by confirmed, row_nmb;
```

Expectations:

```
confirmed | country              | row_nmb |
+-----------+----------------------+---------+
|         1 | Australia            |       1 |
|         1 | Belgium              |       2 |
|         1 | Cambodia             |       3 |
|         1 | Canada               |       4 |
|         2 | China                |       1 |
|         2 | Egypt                |       2 |
|         2 | Finland              |       3 |
|         2 | Germany              |       4 |
|         2 | India                |       5 |
|         2 | Japan                |       6 |
|         2 | Mainland China       |       7 |
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL 8+, use `row_number()`:

```
select confirmed, country,
       row_number() over (partition by confirmed order by country) as row_nmb
from COVID_DB.COVID2019
group by confirmed, country ;
```

In older versions, this is much trickier.  In particular, you cannot set parameters in one expression and use them in another.  To do what you want:

```
select confirmed, country,
       (@rn := if(@c = confirmed, @rn + 1,
                  if(@c := confirmed, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as row_nmb
from (select confirmed, country
      from COVID_DB.COVID2019
      group by confirmed, country
      order by confirmed, country
     ) cc cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @c := -1) params;
```

Variables are deprecated in MySQL 8+, so I strongly encourage you to use the window functions.

Answer (score 0):

The above expectation is met by below code but I just want to know how to compare more than 1 field partition by order by clause .

```
select confirmed, country, province, (@rn := if(@cf = confirmed, @rn + 1, if(@cf := confirmed, 1,1) ) ) as row_nb from  (select confirmed, country, province from COVID_DB.COVID2019 where confirmed in (175, 7153, 1155) order by confirmed, country, province) tb cross join (select @cf := -1, @cn := -1, @pv := -1, @rn := 0) t2;
```